# Hashtable output column titles

Tags: powershell

Consider these 2 hashtables

```
$myHash1 = @{one=1;two=2;three=3;four=4;five=5}
$myHash2 = @{six=6;seven=7;eight=8;nine=9;ten=10}
```

As you can see, they each get a column title when shown on screen.

```
PS C:\> $myHash1

Name         Value
----         -----
four         4
five         5
one          1
three        3
two          2


PS C:\> $myHash2

Name         Value
----         -----
six          6
nine         9
seven        7
ten          10
eight        8
```

However, when I output them both in 1 command, the column titles are shown only once.

```
PS C:\> $myHash1;$myHash2

Name         Value
----         -----
four         4
five         5
one          1
three        3
two          2
six          6
nine         9
seven        7
ten          10
eight        8
```

Even when I add a separator line, the column titles are still only shown once.

```
PS C:\> $myHash1;Write-Output 'separator line';$myHash2

Name         Value
----         -----
four         4
five         5
one          1
three        3
two          2
separator line
six          6
nine         9
seven        7
ten          10
eight        8
```

Why is that?
And is there a way to get the column titles to show again on the output of myHash2 ?
Something like this

```
Name         Value
----         -----
four         4
five         5
one          1
three        3
two          2
separator line
Name         Value
----         -----
six          6
nine         9
seven        7
ten          10
eight        8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason **why** the column titles are omitted in the output of myHash2 is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576715/)

Summary:

> Now, if there is not a registered view for a datatype, then Out-Default looks at the FIRST OBJECT IN THE STREAM to determine how many properties the object has 5 or more properties, it send the ENTIRE STREAM to Format-List, otherwise it sends the ENTIRE STREAM to Format-Table. When it sends the stream to Format-Table, that command needs to generate columns. **It does this by looking at the properties of the FIRST OBJECT – those become the columns. If the first Object has 2 properties, you’ll get a 2 column table even if all the other objects in the stream have 10 properties.**

The comment in that post, made by Ansgar-Wiechers at Jan 10 at 21:28 completes the answer:

> What's relevant is not only the number of columns, but also their title. `$myArray` is displayed as a table with 2 colums `key` and `val`, whereas `$myArray.GetType()` would display tabular output with 4 columns `IsPublic`, `IsSerial`, `Name`, and `BaseType`. Since none of the latter columns have the title `key` or `val`, none of them are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

this should help you :

```
$myHash1 = @{one=1;two=2;three=3;four=4;five=5}
$myHash2 = @{six=6;seven=7;eight=8;nine=9;ten=10}
#you can also use $myHash1 | Out-String also
$myHash1 | ft
Write-Output "separator"
$myHash2 | ft
```

Comment: I second Abhijith. This works well . `$myHash1 | Ft ; $myHash2 | ft`

Comment: I would recommend using Out-String (as mentioned in the comment) instead of format-table. You can at least get some of the data back from out-string if you need to, but format-table output is opaque.

Comment: Does anyone know **why** the column titles are omitted for the 2nd statement?