# No output while running script or function. Only output on command line

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a script file that contains the code below.
It runs the same code 3 times.

1. In the script, inside a function
2. In the script, outside a function
3. Out of the script, on the command line

Source code:

```
Clear-Host

$myKeys = @('key1','key2','key3','key4','key5')
$myValues = @('one','two','three','four','five')

# Declare function
Function Invoke-MyArray
{
    [CmdletBinding()]   param ()

    Write-Output "Function: $($MyInvocation.Mycommand)"

    $myLocalArray = @()

    foreach ($element in $myKeys)
    {
        $key = $element
        $val = $myValues[$myKeys.IndexOf($key)]

        $myObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            key = $key
            val = $val
        }   

        $myLocalArray += $myObject
    }

    Write-Output '### 1 ### $myArray'
    Write-Output '------------------'
    $myArray

    Write-Output '### 2 ### $myArray.getType()'
    Write-Output '----------------------------'
    $myArray.getType()

    Write-Output '### 3 ### $myArray.getType() | Out-String'
    Write-Output '-----------------------------------------'
    $myArray.getType() | Out-String



    Write-Output '### 4 ### $myArray[0]'
    Write-Output '---------------------'
    $myArray[0]

    Write-Output '### 5 ### $myArray[0].getType()'
    Write-Output '-------------------------------'
    $myArray[0].getType()

    Write-Output '### 6 ### $myArray[0].getType() | Out-String'
    Write-Output '--------------------------------------------'
    $myArray[0].getType() | Out-String

}

# Call function
Write-Output '====================='
Write-Output '=== Call function ==='
Write-Output '====================='
Invoke-MyArray

Write-Output '==============================================='
Write-Output '=== Execute same code, without the function ==='
Write-Output '==============================================='
# Execute same code, without the function
$myArray = @()

foreach ($element in $myKeys)
{
    $key = $element
    $val = $myValues[$myKeys.IndexOf($key)]

    $myObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        key = $key
        val = $val
    }   

    $myArray += $myObject
}


Write-Output '### 1 ### $myArray'
Write-Output '------------------'
$myArray

Write-Output '### 2 ### $myArray.getType()'
Write-Output '----------------------------'
$myArray.getType()

Write-Output '### 3 ### $myArray.getType() | Out-String'
Write-Output '-----------------------------------------'
$myArray.getType() | Out-String



Write-Output '### 4 ### $myArray[0]'
Write-Output '---------------------'
$myArray[0]

Write-Output '### 5 ### $myArray[0].getType()'
Write-Output '-------------------------------'
$myArray[0].getType()

Write-Output '### 6 ### $myArray[0].getType() | Out-String'
Write-Output '--------------------------------------------'
$myArray[0].getType() | Out-String


Write-Output '===================================='
Write-Output '=== Executed on the command line ==='
Write-Output '===================================='
```

Resulting output:

```
=====================
=== Call function ===
=====================
Function: Invoke-MyArray
### 1 ### $myArray
------------------

key  val  
---  ---  
key1 one  
key2 two  
key3 three
key4 four 
key5 five 
### 2 ### $myArray.getType()
----------------------------

### 3 ### $myArray.getType() | Out-String
-----------------------------------------

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                           



### 4 ### $myArray[0]
---------------------
key1 one  
### 5 ### $myArray[0].getType()
-------------------------------

### 6 ### $myArray[0].getType() | Out-String
--------------------------------------------

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object                                                                          



===============================================
=== Execute same code, without the function ===
===============================================
### 1 ### $myArray
------------------
key1 one  
key2 two  
key3 three
key4 four 
key5 five 
### 2 ### $myArray.getType()
----------------------------

### 3 ### $myArray.getType() | Out-String
-----------------------------------------

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                           



### 4 ### $myArray[0]
---------------------
key1 one  
### 5 ### $myArray[0].getType()
-------------------------------

### 6 ### $myArray[0].getType() | Out-String
--------------------------------------------

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object                                                                          



====================================
=== Executed on the command line ===
====================================


PS C:\>     Write-Output '### 1 ### $myArray'
    Write-Output '------------------'

### 1 ### $myArray
------------------
PS C:\> $myArray

key  val  
---  ---  
key1 one  
key2 two  
key3 three
key4 four 
key5 five 


PS C:\>     Write-Output '### 2 ### $myArray.getType()'
    Write-Output '----------------------------'

### 2 ### $myArray.getType()
----------------------------
PS C:\> $myArray.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                           


PS C:\>     Write-Output '### 3 ### $myArray.getType() | Out-String'
    Write-Output '-----------------------------------------'

### 3 ### $myArray.getType() | Out-String
-----------------------------------------
PS C:\> $myArray.getType() | Out-String

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                           



PS C:\>     Write-Output '### 4 ### $myArray[0]'
    Write-Output '---------------------'

### 4 ### $myArray[0]
---------------------
PS C:\>     $myArray[0]


key  val
---  ---
key1 one


PS C:\>     Write-Output '### 5 ### $myArray[0].getType()'
    Write-Output '-------------------------------'

### 5 ### $myArray[0].getType()
-------------------------------
PS C:\>     $myArray[0].getType()


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object                                                                          


PS C:\>     Write-Output '### 6 ### $myArray[0].getType() | Out-String'
    Write-Output '--------------------------------------------'

### 6 ### $myArray[0].getType() | Out-String
--------------------------------------------
PS C:\>     $myArray[0].getType() | Out-String


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                               
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object                                                                          


PS C:\>
```

Notice that the `.getType()` call is always empty (no result), except when called directly from the command line.

Only when `.getType()` is piped to `Out-String`, we see a result being printed inside of the script.

Why can't I get an output inside my script and/or function with `.getType()` only?

**EDIT** (after being marked as duplicate by Ansgar Wiechers):
The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441054/formatting-issues-missing-data-when-multiple-commands-use-select-object-within) contains a [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/29/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works/) to an MSDN article that states:

> *Now, if there is not a registered view for a datatype, then
>   Out-Default looks at the FIRST OBJECT IN THE STREAM to determine how
>   many properties the object has 5 or more properties, it send the
>   ENTIRE STREAM to Format-List, otherwise it sends the ENTIRE STREAM to
>   Format-Table.  When it sends the stream to Format-Table, that command
>   needs to generate columns.  **It does this by looking at the properties
>   of the FIRST OBJECT – those become the columns.  If the first Object
>   has 2 properties, you’ll get a 2 column table even if all the other
>   objects in the stream have 10 properties.***

`$myArray` is an array with objects that have 2 properties.
So, I would expect to get a 2-column table in the output stream.
Instead I get no output at all.
In that sense, it's not really a duplicate question, but it sure is related.

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, same result. No output when executing the `.getType()` line, but when typing in `$myArray.getType()` on the debug command line, I do get an output.  I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: My point is that if you've hit a breakpoint you can see the values of the variables in the function's scope, so you can see what `$myArray` actually contains, and you can see whether `$myArray.GetType()` works in the console while debugging. You have the best options for troubleshooting that way.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have debugged it, and have seen that `$myArray` contains data. My problem is that `$myArray.getType()` doesn't print any output when called within the script. I don't know why that is.

Comment: You're having the same formatting issue as the person asking the other question (see link at the top of your question). Jeffrey Snover explained the behavior [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/29/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works/).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Could you please reopen this question? See my edit for explanation why it is different from your duplicate.

Comment: It's still a duplicate. What's relevant is not only the number of columns, but also their title. `$myArray` is displayed as a table with 2 colums `key` and `val`, whereas `$myArray.GetType()` would display tabular output with 4 columns `IsPublic`, `IsSerial`, `Name`, and `BaseType`. Since none of the latter columns have the title `key` or `val`, none of them are displayed.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ah yes indeed. You are correct. I get it now. Thanks for the additional clarification.